# Not able to run stripe_sdk example in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, stripe-payments, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to run the `stripe_sdk` dependency with flutter and using firebase. But I am getting build error while running the example of the sdk. Below are the error details. How should I resolve it?

> ../lib/src/ui/screens/payment_methods_screen.dart:151:39: Error: The
> getter 'ScaffoldMessenger' isn't defined for the class
> 'PaymentMethodsList'.
>
> - 'PaymentMethodsList' is from 'package:stripe_sdk/src/ui/screens/payment_methods_screen.dart'
>   ('../lib/src/ui/screens/payment_methods_screen.dart'). Try correcting
>   the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or
>   field named 'ScaffoldMessenger'.
>   ScaffoldMessenger.of(rootContext).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
>   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to document https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/scaffold-messenger 
`ScaffoldMessenger` Landed in version: `1.23.0-13.0.pre` In `stable` release: `not yet`

current release version is `1.22.5` , `12/11/2020` 
You can do

```
flutter channel master
flutter upgrade
```

Comment: But will it run on android and iOS?

Comment: Yes. ScaffoldMessenger is part of Flutter framework. it can run on Android and iOS

Comment: you can use flutter doctor to check your current version

Comment: But I won't be able to integrate with the flutter app build in flutter stable version. how should I do that? Because the app build in stable version won't run under master version for the same.

Comment: @michaeljohnson, Need to reproduce, could you post minimum reproduce code to a new question and error message you encounter. to allow more people can help you.